# How to fix PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CLOB got -

Tags: plsql

I did this pl sql function to retrieve oracle data in xml format. 
But i got this error:
**PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CLOB got -**

here is my pl sql code:

```
create or replace PACKAGE  PAYROLL AS

        FUNCTION get_all_payroll_transactions return  clob;

END PAYROLL;

FUNCTION get_all_payroll_transactions return  clob IS
  ret  clob;

   BEGIN 
      SELECT XMLElement( "transaction", //this line shows error
                    XMLElement("salary_year", SALYR),
                    XMLElement("salary_month", SALMT),
                    XMLElement("employee_id", EMPID),
                    XMLElement("department_code", DPTID),
                    XMLElement("salary_head", SALHD),
                    XMLElement("description", DESCRP),
                    XMLElement("amount", ALAMT),
                    XMLElement("operator_id", OPID),
                    XMLElement("transaction_date", TRADT)
     ) AS clob into ret FROM PAYROLLFILE; 


COMMIT;

RETURN '<result><status affectedRow='||ret||'>success</status></result>';
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RETURN '<result><status>Error</status></result>';

   END get_all_payroll_transactions;
```

I think there might be some clob , xml cast conversion problem.
please help me.thanks

Comment: This is similar to your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585043/how-to-fix-error34-26-pl-sql-ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-cha).  And you appear to have the same problem still.

Comment: yes please help @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: I think you are on the right track with trying to cast, but shouldn't the parentheses be around the outer most `XMLElement` ?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  can you show me please.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to cast, why not select into an XMLTYPE and then use .getClobVal() to return the value? For example:

```
FUNCTION get_all_payroll_transactions return clob IS
  lXml xmltype;
BEGIN 
  SELECT XMLElement( "transaction",
                XMLElement("salary_year", SALYR),
                XMLElement("salary_month", SALMT),
                XMLElement("employee_id", EMPID),
                XMLElement("department_code", DPTID),
                XMLElement("salary_head", SALHD),
                XMLElement("description", DESCRP),
                XMLElement("amount", ALAMT),
                XMLElement("operator_id", OPID),
                XMLElement("transaction_date", TRADT)
 ) into lXml FROM PAYROLLFILE; 

RETURN '<result><status affectedRow='|| lXml.getClobVal() ||'>success</status></result>';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN '<result><status>Error</status></result>';

END get_all_payroll_transactions;
```